# DatePicker Mask not displayed pasted date when date format is D/M/YYYY

Tags: angular, material-ui, text-mask

I am using Angular2-Text-Mask to implement masking on a Mat-Date-Picker Control.
Controls works all good except Copy-paste operation.

On pasting date as 09-08-2015 >> datepicker takes the date correctly.
On Pasting date as 19-08-2015 >> daatepicker takes the date correctly.
On pasting date as 9-8-2015 >> Datepicker does not show any data untill you move the focus away. though it displays the date correctly after focus is shifted.

Here's snippet of HTML and Mask

```
 <mat-form-field [textMask]="{mask: mask, keepCharPositions: true, pipe: autoCorrectedDatePipe,guide:true}" >
            <mat-label>Employment Date</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="EmploymentDate"
                   [matDatepicker]="EmploymentDate"
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="EmploymentDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #EmploymentDate></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

and below is the mask :

public mask = [/[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '/', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, '/', /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/, /[0-9]/];
public autoCorrectedDatePipe: any = createAutoCorrectedDatePipe('dd/mm/yyyy');

Any suggestions welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by extending the NativeDateAdapter class and updating the `parse` function.

```
@Injectable()

export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    parse(value: any): Date | null {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }
    // check whether user is using /, . or - for entering dates
    if (value.search('/' || '.' || '-') !== -1) {
      return new Date(value);
    } else {
      let day;
      let month;
      let year;
      // Converts 02022021
      if (value.length === 8) {
          month = +value.substring(0, 2);
          day = +value.substring(2, 4);
          year = +value.substring(4, 8);
      }
      return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
    }
  }
}
```

You will also need to provide your DateAdapter in each module that imports MatDatePicker or at root (preferable in my opinion for larger apps to reduce redundancy).

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: CustomDateAdapter
    },
  ]
```